# Tensorflow: Tokenizing bi-grams and n-grams using the Tensorflow Datasets utilities

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tokenize

A number of text classification models and embedding models use uni-gram, bi-gram, and n-grams as tokens for analysis. I found a way to use the `tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()` to extract uni-grams or words from some textual data. However, I wanted to see if there is a way to use the Tokenizer to extract bi-grams or n-grams from the text? I checked the documentation and did not see a setting for the size of each n-gram, but perhaps I missed something.

The code to extract n-grams comes from one of the tutorials on the Tensorflow website:

```
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

vocabulary_set = set()

for text_tensor, _ in all_labeled_data:
    some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text_tensor.numpy())
    vocabulary_set.update(some_tokens)

vocab_size = len(vocabulary_set)
print(f'Vocabulary size is: {vocab_size}')
```

Comment: This link can be useful https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22991/n-grams-in-nlp-deep-learning

Comment: @JaviGonzalez Oh I get it. So n-grams are not as important as I thought. That just individual words are enough, and then you can train an LSTM to figure out which n-grams should go together based upon the data.